# Can I use 2 exact same switching power supplies in parallel?

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, parallel

I would like to achieve 6 amps with those, is it possible?

[image: Connectors]
[image: LED Power S-38-12]

Comment: Short answer: No, long answer: NooOooOo.

Comment: or Maybe if each supply must be matched voltage < 0.1V and have added series R of at least 0.2V @2A (0.1ohm) with a minimum load of 10% or 0.2A each to  reduce risk of oscillation.

Comment: @HarrySvensson Thanks! I will have two to play with then :P

Comment: @MikeGleasonjrCouturier YeeEEaaAHhh! Timmy!